# css grid animation in react

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, css-grid

I trying to build an application in react with CSS Grid with three column layout

```
<div>
  <div class="sidebar"><button>collapse list</button></div> // 100px
  <div class="list"></div> // 200px
  <div class="item-detail"></div> //auto
</div>
```

When I click on the **collapse list** button on side bar, I need to hide the `list` div and expand the `item-detail` div with an slide in and out animation

I have tried by adding class `hidden` on `list` and `expanded` to `item-detail`

```
.item-detail.expanded{
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
}

.list{
  -webkit-animation: slide-in .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-in .3s ease-out;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

This works as expected when showing the list but while hiding it is so abrupt(no animation) as `display:none` happens immediately. How can I achieve the both way animation?

Comment: You can't animate the `display` property or CSS-Grid properties (in the main).

Comment: is that mean we don't have any alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the width of `list` to 0 when `hidden` class is added like below:

```
.list{
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```